# Exposing an API as multiple named pipe (FIFO) files in C

Tags: c, linux, file, posix, fifo

I'm creating a C application daemon that I want to be able to interact with through named pipes. For example, I write in the shell `echo hello > /tmp/appname/interface`, and the application reads it and does stuff with what I just echoed into the named pipe.

I've successfully managed to implement this with a singular named pipe with `read()`. However, I want to be able to listen to many different named pipes at the same time. I don't think spawning a new thread for each named pipe is a very good solution. I am also concerned about whether constantly listening for something to be written to the named pipes with `read()` will use an unnecessarily high amount of CPU. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Here's a link that can interest you: [how to read multiple serial ports in realtime in C or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234078/how-to-read-multiple-serial-ports-in-realtime-in-c-or-python). This is about serial ports but you may hit the same problem.

Comment: read is a blocking read - doesn't use a lot of cpu - it just sits there.  If you are polling, then it will use a lot of CPU.  If you are using a blocking read then the only way to listen to multiple pipes is by using threads.  Also do a stack overflow search on how to terminate blocked I/O.