# How to check correct writting to Serial device /dev/ttySX in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I need to implement a specific protocol over a serial device. I have already done the message contructor and have a list of bytes ready to be send. The issue that I am having is that I am not able to verify if I am correctly sending the bytes into the `/dev/ttyS2` interface. My serial messages follow the structure `PATTERN + MESSAGE`

I am able to read from the serial device and filter some received known messages by doing:

```
cat /dev/ttyS2 | grep PATTERN
```

In my program (code below), if I send my message I amb not able to see my frames using the previous command:

```
static FILE * file_stream = NULL;
static int file_des = 0;

static void printSampleMessage(void) {
struct termios SerialPortSettings; /* Create the structure                          */

/* Open linux device */
file_des = open("/dev/ttyS2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

/*---------- Setting the Attributes of the serial port using termios structure --------- */

tcgetattr(file_des, &SerialPortSettings);   /* Get the current attributes of the Serial port */

/* Setting the Baud rate */
cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B38400); /* Set Read  Speed as 38400                       */
cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B38400); /* Set Write Speed as 38400                       */

/* 8N1 Mode */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;   /* Disables the Parity Enable bit(PARENB),So No Parity   */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;   /* CSTOPB = 2 Stop bits,here it is cleared so 1 Stop bit */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;    /* Clears the mask for setting the data size             */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;      /* Set the data bits = 8                                 */

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;       /* No Hardware flow Control                         */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; /* Enable receiver,Ignore Modem Control lines       */


SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);          /* Disable XON/XOFF flow control both i/p and o/p */
SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);  /* Non Cannonical mode                            */

SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; /*No Output Processing RAW mode*/


if((tcsetattr(file_des,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings)) != 0) {/* Set the attributes to the termios structure*/
} else {
}

/* Obtain file stream descriptor */
file_stream = fdopen(file_des, "r+");
fputs ( "PATTERN+MESSAGE", file_stream);
}
```

However, I am not able to see my own message when using the `cat /dev/ttyS2 | grep PATTERN` command. How can I check if I am actually sending my **PATTERN+ message** in the serial device?

I am quite limited in terms of program options. My setup is an embedded linux communicating with another microcontroller within a board (no test point to connect a physical sniffer) and no minicom available as the linux distribution I am using is very basic, I can not just `apt-get install XX`

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57157995/11476836) might help.

Comment: "Reliable" protocols do not *"verify if I am correctly sending the bytes"*.  The receiver of the message verifies the integrity of the received data (using a checksum or even better CRC), and responds with an ACK or NAK.  IOW you *"verify"* that the message has been received, not that it has been sent.

Comment: I am developing the protocol, therefore before trying to even implement the receiving part I want to assert that the sender is correct. Trying to read from a prototype device the bytes I am sending from another prototype device is in my opinion a bad aproach to development as there are multiple possibe points of failure

Comment: @MarcosG. I am working on an embedded linux platform and interceptty is not aviable.

Comment: Your "explanation" about `cat /dev/ttyS2 ...` fails to describe what you are doing.  Do you expect to read what was already transmitted?    You cannot *"check if I am actually sending my PATTERN+ message **in** the serial device"*.  You have to go external to the UART, i.e. actually connect something to the transmit line.  You could do a loopback, but it's a half-baked test because TX and RX share configuration in the UART and the line settings aren't tested.  BTW `Busybox` can be built with a `picocom`.

Comment: *"My setup (has) no test point to connect a physical sniffer"* -- If the SoC and uP are separate chips then you need to look for exposed circuit trace.  If the interprocessor link is truly not accessible, then IMO you have a poorly designed  board.  Making the board testable for both HW and SW should have been a goal.