# how do you open FTDI serial ports ttyUSBx such that we can run 2 applications on it?

Tags: linux, serial-port, pyserial, linux-mint

I am writing a python pyserial app and need to debug it. It is not getting anything on its rx beyond the prompt. I would like to open up a parallel minicom on same tty and be able to see the port rx.
Is this possible without hardware logging ? Can I simply use a serial settings to allow 2 apps to run simultaneously on ttyUSB0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't access your serial ports from two processes at the same time.

There are workarounds that can give you a much cheaper solution than purchasing a hardware sniffer or a scope with serial decoding capabilities though.

You will have to define a couple of virtual serial ports and use port forwarding. This procedure has been explained here: on [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153141/cant-use-interceptty-or-slsnif-to-sniff-data-sent-via-serial-port/57157995#57157995) and Windows [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056042/i-am-sending-commands-through-serial-port-in-python-but-they-are-sent-multiple-t/57062146#57062146), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359916/use-serial-uart-output-as-input-in-other-serial-terminal-on-windows-10/56377015#56377015).